# Format Conditions apply through Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know that how Duplicate condition is applied through Macro.
Means that, If in given range (C11:C510) the Duplicate value are entered, then Font Color changes to Red and also Strikethrough is applied through Conditional Formatting (Except the word: "Applicable") then how it could work through macro.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
Sub CheckDuplicates()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("C11:C510"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        For Each cell In .Cells
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Resize(cell.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1), cell.Value) > 1 Then
                With cell
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    .Font.Strikethrough = True
                End With
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i get error on    "For Each cell In .Cells". error message: Object Variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

Comment: @Rafael - make sure the active sheet contains the cell range.  Let me know if error still persists.

Comment: Hi Mrig Thanks you have done a great job. I also requested for one exceptional word i.e. "Applicable" which I have done by adding two lines of code i.e. (If cell.Value <> "Applicable" Then) and finish it with its (End If), which also works. Once again thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: @MuneebHussain - glad my answer worked for you. If it solves your problem kindly accept it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks and apologies that I wont accept your answer because I wont aware where to click. Now I've accepted by looking through this forum.